# Xcode error "cannot set a default platform"

Tags: xcode

I dont know if this fits stackoverflow.com, but I cant even open Xcode. It just gives me this error "The MAC OS X platform is missing - cannot set default platform."

I have just installed Xcode. I dont get the error message, and I have never seen it before. Cant find anything on google.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint in form of a link, or paper?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I have done a complete reinstall of OS X with out zero writing the harddisk first. I have solved the problem by simple zero write the harddisk, and then reinstalled OS X again. Now I can use Xcode.